# How to read/debug javascript console when using wx.html2.WebView

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using [wx.html2.WebView](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html) to visit a url which returns some simple html/javascript. The problem I'm running into is that when I visit the url using firefox and internet explorer the code runs fine, but when using the webview I get an undefined object error. Is there any way to debug javascript errors with `webview`?

Here's my example

```
import wx, traceback
from wx.html2 import WebView, EVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR, EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW, \
    WEBVIEWIE_EMU_IE11


html = """<HTML lang=en><HEAD><TITLE>Payments</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Loading.....</H1>
loading stripe
<SCRIPT src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></SCRIPT>
done loading stripe
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
try {
    document.writeln('creating Stripe object');
    // error occurs here, Stripe is undefined
    var stripe = Stripe('<PUBLIC KEY GOES HERE>');
    document.writeln('redirecting to checkout');
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: '<SESSION ID GOES HERE>'
    }).then(function (result) {
    });
    document.writeln('done calling javascript');
}
catch(error) {
    document.writeln('error occurred: ' + error.message);
}
</SCRIPT>
<H1>....DONE</H1></BODY></HTML>  """


class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, size=(1000, 800))
        self._times_loaded = 0
        self.webview = WebView.New(self)  # type: WebView
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR, self.on_error)
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, self.on_loaded)
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, self.on_navigate)
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW, self.on_new_window)
        # wx.CallAfter(self.load_gateway)
        wx.CallAfter(self.load_html)

        self.Show()

    # def load_gateway(self, evt=None):
    #     self.webview.LoadURL(url)

    def load_html(self):
        self.webview.SetPage(html, "www.stripe.com")

    def reset_page(self):
        self.webview.SetPage(self.webview.GetPageSource(), url)

    # def redirect_to_checkout(self):
    #     # stripe.
    #     session= stripe.checkout.session.Session.create(test_stripe_public_key)

    def on_error(self, evt):
        print(f"error occurred: {evt}")

    def on_navigate(self, evt):
        print("on navigate")

    def on_loaded(self, evt):
        print("loaded")
        self._times_loaded += 1

    def on_new_window(self, evt):
        print("new window event")


try:
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
except:
    input(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Maybe the Stripe script is not fetched from the server? You can use a network sniffer such as Wireshark to see this.

Comment: I have used [IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/jj126732(v%3Dvs.85)) in a C++ wxWidgets app to see console messages. Not sure how to use this from wxPython though.

Comment: I rewrote the script to call the stripe script after the window loads, and then call the redirect script after that loads and it still didn't work. Finally removing the `writeln` calls fixed it. The console wouldn't have even helped me in this situation, but I would like to know how to get that output. I'll look into the message receiver